# Program resolution is too small on the screen

Tags: customization

I just installed Blender and have a 2000x3000 tablet. I can't read the the labels on the program. Is there an easier way to do it rather than changing the laptop resolution?

Comment: Hi. Typing everything in capitals is generally considered to be shouting. Please don't shout.

Answer (score 1):

Open *File > User Preferences*, under *Interface* adjust *Display Scale*

[image: Display Scale]